# prevent validation messages raised by hibernate to be displayed in JSF [age

Tags: hibernate, jsf, bean-validation

I have Min and Max annotations over my JPA entity
code example

```
@Min(value=1)
private int id;
@Max(value=10)
private int count;
//getters and setters
```

in JSF page a message is returned from these annotations and i also added my own validation (JSF validation) wherei need my own msg
in validation case 2 messages are show the hibernate message reffering to Min and Max annotation and my f:validateXXX message
what i want is to keep the annotations but prevent hibernate message to be displayed in my page and not to skip validation only skip showing hibernate messages and keep my own message

Comment: Could you clarify your question by adding the jsf code as well? Do you have a mixture of _validateBean_ and other _validateXYZ_ methods? Do you want Bean Validation to occur as part of the JSF or JPA life cycle? If you don't want Bean Validation to occur on the JSf side you could set the property _javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR_. Or maybe you just want to add your own resource bundle with your own messages by adding a custom _ValidationMessages_? Again, it really depends what exactly you want.

Comment: i do not have validateXYZ methods i have only validateBean which is min and max and f:validateLongRange in the jsf page i want Bean Validation to occur as JPA lifecycle but where to put this property javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR where to use it

Comment: what exactly i want is to keep Bean Validation at entity side and add jsf validation f:validateLongRange to that if jsf validation is skipped in any way there will be a validation bean which catch the validation before persistence but i don't want to display the bean validation messages just messages thrown by f:validateLongRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to disable Bean Validation as part of JSF via adding the following to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```